# What is the recommended way to respond to bad user input with a REST API?

Tags: c#, json, rest, xamarin

Let's assume the following:

- I have a rest API that will return me names of fruits, and there are only 5 fruits.
- To get the fruit name, I have to request an ID.

Consider the following code:

```
public class Fruit {
    public int FruitID { get; set; }
    public string FruitName { get; set; }
    public Fruit(string json){
        JObject o = JObject.Parse(json);
        FruitID = Int32.Parse((string) o["id"]);
        FruitName = (string) o["name");
    }
}

public static Fruit getFruit(int id){
    Task<Fruit> task = "http://fruit.com/get_fruit"
        .SetQueryParams(new { fruit_id = id })
        .GetStringAsync();
    return new Fruit(task.Result);
}
```

(If anything looks wrong at this point please correct me, I am new to C# Tasks)

Let's say when that Task returns, the json could look like the following if it received a valid ID...

```
{
    "status":1,
    "id": 3,
    "name": "apple"
}
```

Or this if it received an invalid ID.

```
{
    "status":0
}
```

If the user is supposed to enter which ID is searched for, then there is a chance they could enter an ID which does not exist, since there are only 5, (0 through 4). Based on the code I entered above, I can see the application crashing if a `"status":0` is returned, as it would not have the two fields the class constructor is looking for.

My question is: What is the best way to handle possible invalid inputs (such as the user entering ID of 20)?

Answer (score 2):

The recommended way for a RESTful API is to use HTTP Error codes, in your case it would be 404 (Not found), since the fruit requested does not exist.
You should handle the error codes before trying to create the object. So check whether the request has been successfully executed (200 OK), and then process the payload.

Here's a reference of status codes:
http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html

Comment: I see where you're coming from, except the API I'm using doesn't return 404's. It returns a `"status":0`. I can speak to the API manager about that.

Comment: The idea would be similar though, you should process the status before the entity. In that example, check whether the status was "1", then parse the Fruit, otherwise handle the error status (0)

Answer (score 0):

input validation is one of the important tasks in web service development. i personally have two phase. at first i check the object for null values. i wrote this method in order to do it:

```
private bool HasNull(object webServiceInput, string[] optionalParameters = null)
{

    if (ReferenceEquals(null, webServiceInput))
        return false;

    if (optionalParameters == null)
        optionalParameters = new string[0];

    var binding = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public;
    var properties = webServiceInput.GetType().GetProperties(binding);
    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        if (!property.CanRead)
            continue;

        if (property.PropertyType.IsValueType)
            continue;

        if (optionalParameters.Contains(property.Name))
            continue;

        var value = property.GetValue(webServiceInput);
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, value))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

then if some of the inputs should have specified validation i check it individually. for example i check the ID be between 0 and 5;
i hope it could help you.